# what might be the cause of a numberpicker nullpointer (with Tourguide)?

Tags: android, viewgroup

So I have a numberpicker and a datepicker, everythings working except when my views are associated with tourguide library https://github.com/worker8/TourGuide ,

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:2988)
        at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12428)
        at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12545)
        at android.view.HardwareRenderer$GlRenderer.draw(HardwareRenderer.java:1184)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2446)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2306)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2109)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1127)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4606)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:747)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:567)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:536)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4987)
```

the error above was thrown only when i click on either top or bottom selection of the picker and not when i slide the picker, its weird because when tourguide is off the error was not thrown.

i call this method for all of my numberpicker and datepicker

```
 public void pickerfix(View np) {
    np.setSaveFromParentEnabled(false);
    np.setSaveEnabled(true);
    if (np.getId() == R.id.datepicker) {
        ((DatePicker) np).setDescendantFocusability(NumberPicker.FOCUS_BLOCK_DESCENDANTS);
    } else {
        ((NumberPicker) np).setDescendantFocusability(NumberPicker.FOCUS_BLOCK_DESCENDANTS);
    }
  }
```

and this line of code on every onValueChange to dismiss the tourguide..

```
 if(askTutorial == 1){
                tuts.dismissTourguide();}
```

what might be the cause of nullpointer? i tried putting an onclicklistener to the pickers and put the dismiss line but no luck.

!!! added
so this is my code for datepicker

```
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int d = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    c.set(Calendar.YEAR, d - 2);
    Calendar c2 = Calendar.getInstance();
    c2.set(Calendar.YEAR, d - 130);
    datePicker.setMinDate(c2.getTimeInMillis());
    datePicker.setMaxDate(c.getTimeInMillis());
    datePicker.init(c.get(Calendar.YEAR), c.get(Calendar.MONTH), c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), new DatePicker.OnDateChangedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDateChanged(DatePicker view,
                                  int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
            if(askTutorial == 1){
                tuts.dismissTourguide();}
        }


    });
```

and my number picker

```
 pickerfix(npKg);
    npKg.setMinValue(10);
 npKg.setMaxValue(650);
    npKg.setOnValueChangedListener(new NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onValueChange(NumberPicker numberPicker, int i, int i1) {

            if(askTutorial == 1){
                tuts.dismissTourguide();}
        }
    });
```

generally i have more than 1 numberpicker but i think this will do,.

my tourguide display is called on a different class same with the dismiss call.

```
    public void showProfileTutorial(View v, String bgcolor, int txt){

    Animation animation = new TranslateAnimation(0f, 0f, 200f, 0f);
    animation.setDuration(1000);
    animation.setFillAfter(true);
    animation.setInterpolator(new BounceInterpolator());

    Animation exitAnimation = new AlphaAnimation(1f, 0f);
    exitAnimation.setDuration(200);
    exitAnimation.setFillAfter(true);


    String[] splitter = texts[txt].split(":");
    toolTip = new ToolTip()
            .setTitle(splitter[0])
            .setDescription(splitter[1])
            .setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#bdc3c7"))
            .setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#30BA8F"))
            .setShadow(true)
            .setGravity(grav1| grav2)
            .setEnterAnimation(animation);

    overlay = new Overlay()
            .disableClick(disableClick)
            .setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(bgcolor))
            .setStyle(Overlay.Style.Circle)
            .setExitAnimation(exitAnimation);

    pointer = new Pointer().setColor(Color.RED).setGravity(Gravity.CENTER | Gravity.CENTER);

    mTourGuideHandler = TourGuide.init(activity).with(TourGuide.Technique.Click);
    mTourGuideHandler.setPointer(null);
    mTourGuideHandler.setToolTip(toolTip);
    mTourGuideHandler.setOverlay(overlay);
    mTourGuideHandler.playOn(v);

}


public void dismissTourguide(){
    try{
        //.e("Before", "clean");
        mTourGuideHandler.cleanUp();
        //Log.e("After", "clean");
    }catch (Exception e){

    }
}
```

Comment: You need to add more code in your activity class

Comment: @NollyJ added some codes, although i removed some unnecessary or unrelated method calling, just tell me if im still missing something..

Answer (score 1):

First try this modification and see if it will work but I think it is related to concurrency issue -

```
public void dismissTourguide(){
    try{
        if(null != mTourGuideHandler){
             mTourGuideHandler.cleanUp();
        }
    }catch (Exception e){}
}
```

Comment: you know what youre partially right, the dimiss call is what causes the error, but what i did is remove the dismisstourguide call on every onvaluechange then creates onclicklisteners and put it there, it's not actually what i wanted (how it behave), but it removes the error, so i think ill stick with it..